# Async: run single function

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

All async.js operators seem to be made for collections only. Is there a way to run this piece of code:

```
async.series([
            function (callback) {
              TripDao.getTrip(callback);
            }],
            function done(error, result) {
              var trip = result[0];
              // things to do with trip
            }
    );
```

In this way?

```
async.runSingle(function(callback){
          TripDao.getTrip(callback);
       },
       function done(error, trip){
          // things to do with trip
       }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you only need to execute one function, why not just pass it a callback?

```
TripDao.getTrip(function (error, trip) {
    // things to do with trip
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to handle the response in a common way across the app. So this is not the way...

Comment: Man, you are right! I started to think in a too complex way.